# Cannot type password in Azure Power Shell

Tags: bash, azure, powershell, elasticsearch

In created Elasticserach on Azure. Azure created different VMs, network etc. that is needed. Now I want to access to Kibana via ssh. In the PowerShell or Shell Terminal in the Azure Portal, it won't let me type the password. Somehow I cannot type enything. Can someone help me why is this?

[image]

Comment: just type password and hit enter (you don't see stars or something) but it takes inputs..

Comment: Alright, I will give a try

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The SSH command does not support input the password within itself. You just can input the password in the stdin. And the stdin is also invisible so that you cannot see what you have inputted. You only can input the password following your feelings. If you do not trust your feelings, you can copy the password from another space and then paste it in the stdin.